# Just upgraded to Ubuntu 14...won't start up

Tags: upgrade, system-installation

Hi I have a pretty nice computer that I just built and it has been on Ubuntu 13.10 for a while but today when I tried to upgrade it to 14.04, everything went fine until the system rebooted.  Now my monitor is just stuck on the "Ubuntu" screen and the loading dots are just red and aren't doing anything. The only time they seem to move is when I restated the system to try again. Any ideas?? 
EDIT: After I hit "up arrow" when the dots appeared the last line says "saned disabled; edit..." but I can't get it to say this again, every time I do this the script only shows for a matter of seconds and then the screen goes black

Comment: Restart your computer. When the dots first start appearing, hit Up Arrow. You will see lots of output on the screen. When it stops, note down the last few lines and add this information **in your question above.**

Answer (score 0):

For the future it would be a great idea to use TimeSift. You can do backups and in your situation it would be helpful. I swear on this program. It saved my Ubuntu-PC a few times.
I hope for you someone can help you anyway.